# Extract URL's inclusive with fragments in string using Python with Regex

Tags: python, regex, url

Ok i know ppl are going to say this question has been asked a million times.. but my question is **DIFFERENT**. I have searched stackoverflow many many many times to ensure this is not a duplicate..

I want a regex in **Python** that also helps to extract the URL from a string **INCLUDING FRAGMENTS**

What i have done so far is:

```
import re

test = 'This is a string with my URL as follows http://www.example.org/foo.html#bar and here i continue with my string'

test = re.findall('http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+', test)

print (test)
```

> > The output i get for the above code is ['http://www.example.org/foo.html']

Which is not what i want..

> > I want to the output to be ['http://www.example.org/foo.html#bar']

Comment: *Different*, that's what they all say...

Comment: [Don't reinvent the wheel](https://gist.github.com/gruber/249502)

Comment: P.S. You can shorten `[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]` to `[-\w$@.&+!*(),]` which also removes your incorrect range. Or even cooler is `[\w$@&(-.]`

Comment: shortening is not what i want i want the entire URL as it is.

Comment: @Uraforclain I'm shortening, but also improving. The shorter version doesn't include an incorrect range. For example, explain to me why your regex matches `/`. You never specified it in your set ;)

Comment: What you are doing results in me having an output of http:// www.example.org i want http:// www.example.org/foo.html#bar  i need everything that is after including /foo.html#bar

Comment: @Uraforclain I know what you're looking for, but I'm telling you that your regex is not correct at the moment. It's including characters between `$` and `_`, which happens to be `$%&'()*+,-./0123456789:;<=>?@ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ[\]^_`. Right now your regex will match `http://;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your original regex is this:

```
http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```

Couldn't you just add '#' Like this?:

```
http[s]?://(?:[a-zA-Z]|[0-9]|[$-_@.&+]|[!*\(\),#]|(?:%[0-9a-fA-F][0-9a-fA-F]))+
```

I am unclear as to what you mean by 'fragments'... Do you mean anything up to the space in the string?

Comment: what i mean by fragments is for the suffix # at the end of the URL.. btw ur answer is right! thanks a lot :)